# How can I override the Sencha Touch data store proxy exception listener?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there any way to add a common or override exception listener to the proxy on a data store object in Sencha touch 2.0 ?

I would like to have a common code for all proxies errorhandling, so I dont need to add the exception listener for all stores.

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?

Comment: Yes, I did. Check answer under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Server, {
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callOverridden([config]);
        this.addListener("exception", callbackfunction);
    }
});

/*
 * Global handler for when an Ajax request returns a failure code. 
 * Runs before the Ext.Ajax.request.faulure event runs.
 */
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', callbackfunction, this);

/*
 * Global handler for when an Ajax request completes successfully. 
 * Runs before the Ext.Ajax.request.success event runs.
 * Shows any enclosed message texts.
 */
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', callbackfunction, this);
```

Comment: Very useful answer and still works even on Ext 6.2!